# I want to hide the lable in infopath 2013

Tags: infopath

I tried to hide the control in infopath form but its label is still displaying.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution # 1**:

you'll need to put it into some control that can be hidden.  You can put both controls in a table within a section and then hide the whole section instead of just the one field.

**Solution # 2**
Create a text box control to use as the label.And hide it based on rules.
[More details here](http://tecfac.net/2014/06/hiding-labels-in-infopath-designer-2013/)