# Hidding the label in infopath 2013

Tags: infopath

I need to hide the label when its related control is also hide in infopath 2013. I tried to hide the control but still the label is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a section control from the toolbox and add your label and respective control inside that section. Now create a rule to hide that section, this will hide the entire row i.e the label and the control. Please refer to the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution # 1:**

you'll need to put it into some control that can be hidden. You can put both controls in a table within a section and then hide the whole section instead of just the one field.

**Solution # 2** 
Create a text box control to use as the label.And hide it based on rules. [More details here](http://tecfac.net/2014/06/hiding-labels-in-infopath-designer-2013/)

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/127896/6382). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Comment: apologies. will keep in mind.

Comment: No worries! Keep up the good answers :-)